# Is it possible to have Flexbox only wrap onto a new line if there is enough space on the cross axis?

Tags: css, flexbox

Can Flexbox be controlled to only wrap items onto a new line if there is enough available space on the cross axis for the items to fit, without overflowing?

Here is an example of when I would like wrapping to occur:

[image: Desired wrapping]

And here is an example of wrapping which I would like to avoid:

[image: Undesired wrapping]

When there is insufficient space for the items on the cross axis, I would prefer to have the items shrink, uniformly, instead of wrapping onto a new line.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.resize {
  height: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get the desired behaviour with `flex`, or perhaps with `grid`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible ...

Comment: as far as i know flex uses only one dimension `ROW` or `COLUMN` and you have to manipulate both. i dont think there is a way to do this with flex - except there is a `wrap-for-column-height` attribute or something similar - ill come back on this tomorrow

Comment: CSS cant't detect overflow/wrapping nor is it *conditional* on the height of a parent element. You will need javascript.

Comment: I usually play with min-width, min-height and flex-basis, flex-shrink, flex-grow.
If it is not enough I prefer to use grid.